# Getting all possible LDAP Attributes of special object classes in AD using C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I have a question regarding this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674203/ldap-retrieve-a-list-of-all-attributes-values/21159544#21159544)

Is it possible to get the first point of JPBlanc's answer:

1. Get all possible user attributes as described in the schema using System.DirectoryServices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I needed:

```
List<string> userPropertyList = new List<string>();
ActiveDirectorySchema currSchema = ActiveDirectorySchema.GetCurrentSchema();
ActiveDirectorySchemaClass collection = currSchema.FindClass("user");
ReadOnlyActiveDirectorySchemaPropertyCollection properties = collection.GetAllProperties();
IEnumerator enumerator = properties.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    userPropertyList.Add(enumerator.Current.ToString());
}
```

To get all possible properties of a group, just change "user" to "group".
This ldap query includes all properties for the subclasses, too.
For e.g. asking all properties for class "user" will include the properties for "tob", "person" and "organizationalPerson".

Thnks to abhitalks for the hint to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is from one of my old projects where I needed to do nearly the same thing. This code snippet is part of a larger test ASP.Net app, hence the `response.write` you could see.

Am sorry, I have it in VB.Net, but am sure you would be able to get it going in C#.

```
Sub GetAllUserInfo(ByVal userName As String)
    Dim strGroup As String
    Dim adRoot As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.local/DC=domain,DC=local")
    Dim adSearch As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(adRoot)
    Dim adResult As DirectoryServices.SearchResult
    adSearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")"
    adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
    adResult = adSearch.FindOne()
    Response.Write("<table>")
    For Each x As DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection In adResult.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties
        Response.Write("<tr><td>")
        Response.Write(x.PropertyName)
        Response.Write("</td><td>")
        Response.Write(x.Value.ToString)
        Response.Write("</td></tr>")
        If x.PropertyName = "memberOf" Then
            For Each s As String In x.Value
                Response.Write("<tr><td>")
                Response.Write("Groups: ")
                Response.Write("</td><td>")
                strGroup = Mid(s, InStr(s, "CN=") + 3, (InStr(InStr(s, "CN=") + 3, s, ",") - (InStr(s, "CN=") + 3)))
                Response.Write(strGroup)
                Response.Write("</td></tr>")
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Response.Write("</table>")
End Sub
```

Ok. Here you go in C#, used an online converter.

```
public void GetAllUserInfo(string userName)
{
    string strGroup = null;
    DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry adRoot = new DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.local/DC=domain,DC=local");
    DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(adRoot);
    DirectoryServices.SearchResult adResult = default(DirectoryServices.SearchResult);
    adSearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
    adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
    adResult = adSearch.FindOne();
    Response.Write("<table>");
    foreach (DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection x in adResult.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties) {
        Response.Write("<tr><td>");
        Response.Write(x.PropertyName);
        Response.Write("</td><td>");
        Response.Write(x.Value.ToString);
        Response.Write("</td></tr>");
        if (x.PropertyName == "memberOf") {
            foreach (string s in x.Value) {
                Response.Write("<tr><td>");
                Response.Write("Groups: ");
                Response.Write("</td><td>");
                strGroup = Strings.Mid(s, Strings.InStr(s, "CN=") + 3, (Strings.InStr(Strings.InStr(s, "CN=") + 3, s, ",") - (Strings.InStr(s, "CN=") + 3)));
                Response.Write(strGroup);
                Response.Write("</td></tr>");
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Write("</table>");
}
```

**Update**:

The above code retrieves only those properties that have a value set. If you need to enumerate all properties in the LDAP schema, you will need to look at the `ActiveDirectorySchema` and `ActiveDirectorySchemaClass` classes in the `DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` namespace.

Getting the schema:

```
ActiveDirectorySchema currentSchema = ActiveDirectorySchema.GetCurrentSchema();
```

Once you have the schema, you can see the classes:

```
ActiveDirectorySchemaClass objClass = currentSchema.FindClass("ldapDisplayName");
```

Where, *ldapDisplayName* is the AD object name, like "person", "computer" etc.

Now, you can enumerate the properties. Make sure you enumerate both `MandatoryProperties` and `OptionalProperties` properties of the class:

```
objClass.MandatoryProperties 
objClass.OptionalProperties
```

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectoryschemaclass.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: thx abhitalks for your answer, but this is not the Thing I Need. I know how to get properties to a Special user. I need to get all possible attributes a user can have.

Comment: `search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("*"); search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("+");` ?

Comment: this does not helps me. If I try it in the way you wrote, I just get the set Properties of the User, not all the user could have

Comment: @skpn: Yes. Sorry, I completely overlooked that. There. I have updated the answer. You are looking for: `ActiveDirectorySchemaClass`.

Comment: thx abhitalks, for your update and your solution. I made some minimal modifications and got what I want. I write my solution as answer to this question.