# Return information about found user Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I am making an Active Directry managment tool but I am having trouble getting somethings working. 
While I made a class where I want to find a specific user and return als his information(Name,Fullname,CN,...). I can find all this information but when I don't know the best way to return all the values from my class.

Here is the code I use so far:

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnectie);
search.Filter = "(cn=" + username + ")";
SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
    if (result != null)
    {
        List<string> listLdapFields = new List<string>();
        List<Object> listLdapValues = new List<Object>();
        ResultPropertyCollection fields = result.Properties;

                foreach (String ldapField in fields.PropertyNames)
                {
                    listLdapFields.Add(ldapField);
                    foreach (Object myCollection in fields[ldapField])
                    {
                        listLdapValues.Add(myCollection);
                    }



                }
            }
```

The program add everything well to a list. But if I return this I cannot search the list on "CN" or "Name". I can only find the information on Index Number.

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....
       // the most often used attributes are available as nice, strongly-typed properties
       string value = user.GivenName;
       value = user.Surname;
       value = user.EmailAddress;
       value = user.VoiceTelephoneNumber;
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach where you can call the property by name. It also uses the authenticated account making the request.

```
string domainPath = String.Format("LDAP://{0},DC=site,DC=com", domain);

using (DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(domainPath))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher search = 
            filterSearch(new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot), username))
    {
        SearchResult result = null;

        try
        {
            result = search.FindOne();
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
        {
            //handle the error
        }

        if (result != null)
        {
            string givenname = result.Properties["givenname"].Count > 0 ? 
                    (string)result.Properties["givenname"][0] : "";

            string sn = result.Properties["sn"].Count > 0 ? 
                    (string)result.Properties["sn"][0] : "";

            var samaccount= result.Properties["samaccountname"].Count > 0 ? 
                    (string)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0] : "";

            var name = String.Format("{0}, {1}", sn, givenname);
            var email = result.Properties["mail"].Count > 0 ? 
                    (string)result.Properties["mail"][0] : "";
        }
    }
}

//Apply a filter to search only specific classes and categories.
//Add the specific properties to be retrieved

private DirectorySearcher filterSearch(DirectorySearcher search, string username)
{
    DirectorySearcher filteredSearch = search;

    filteredSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=" + username + "))";
    filteredSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
    filteredSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
    filteredSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
    filteredSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
    filteredSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("physicalDeliveryOfficeName");
    filteredSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

    return filteredSearch;
}
```

This may be helpful if looking for specific properties, but if you want to retrieve a list of all attributes/values, take a look at this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674203/ldap-retrieve-a-list-of-all-attributes-values).

[Google](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gads/admin/ldap.5.4.html) has a list of common filters you can use. Take a look through them and modify the filterSearch method appropriately.